# Kernel Headers 3.19.0-28 generic was not found?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I am installing vmware player. After successfully running the configuration , when I started it, its giving me the a pop up to locate this package. How to resolve it .

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2):

You could install Kernel generic headers like this:

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

Answer (score 0):

VMWare needs a couple of things in order to run properly.  They can easily be installed by executing the following command from a terminal window

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

This will install the linux-headers-generic for your system, and make sure that some utilities required for compiling programs are installed on your system

Comment: This is so wrong. After the user gets a new version of Linux, their headers will be out of date. That's why there is a metapackage: linux-headers-amd64. That package is always synced with the kernel.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste `linux-headers-generic`?

Comment: @mchid Nope, I meant what I put, assuming you're on a 64-bit system, which the person asking the question probably is since VMware is only available for 64-bit machines now.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste you're probably correct tht I should not have specified the version dependant headers, but it appears `linux-headers-amd64` is not available:  `apt-cache policy linux-headers-amd64` returns no installation candidates

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste you're running debian instead of ubuntu aren't you. That is a debian package that is not available for ubuntu. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-headers-amd64&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all smh maybe you should be on http://unix.stackexchange.com :)